# flash video site problems (firefox/chrome on PC)

Tags: windows, flash, firefox

I'm having problems with this site - http://www.polivision.tv/test.html

In firefox and chrome on my macbook the video plays full screen in the background.

However, my client is complaining about it not working at all on windows computers.  While I thought that most browser compatibility issues were mostly browser based and not OS based, apparently the same site does not work in firefox and chrome on pc's.

I'm not 100% sure, but it might be some sort of a z-index problem?  I heard that the video would show up, but none of the content would.

Any help making the site compatible would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Shoma

Comment: The site works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera here (Win7)

Answer (score 1):

yes it's not working ..(FF 3.6.8, WIn7)

use this code:

```
<object width="1280" height="371" align="middle" id="background-vid" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">

      <param value="true" name="LOOP">
      <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
      <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
      <param value="high" name="quality">
      <param value="#000" name="bgcolor">   
      <embed width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" loop="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" name="background-vid" bgcolor="black" wmode="transparent" quality="high" src="background-vid.swf"><a href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf" class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb"></a><a href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf" class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb"></a><a class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb" href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf"></a><a class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb" href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf"></a><a href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf" class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb"></a><a href="http://www.polivision.tv/background-vid.swf" class="gsadezlntfhpookvpggb"></a>
    </object>
```

following parameters are missing:

```
<object .... >
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<embed .... wmode="transparent">
</object>
```

just add 'em and that's it :D
btw nice work :)

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have gotten it to work on FF and Chrome.

Does anyone have any solution for IE?  Apparently the video is not even viewable...